# Arduino c++ First letter of string missing

Tags: c++, arduino, serial-port

I'm receiving a string from one serial port and repeating to a second serial port. The following code works, but the first letter (number 4 in this case) of the string is missing.

```
while(Serial1.available()){
  MyString = Serial1.readString();  
}
client.print(MyString);
```

The end result is `"192A4BF,0,3.999023"` when it should be `"4192A4BF,0,3.999023"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reading from `Serial1` in a loop, overwriting all strings that you receive except for the last one.  What likely happens is that you first read — and discard — `4` and then read — and print — the rest.

Moving the `print` into the loop should fix this:

```
while(Serial1.available()){
  MyString = Serial1.readString();
  client.print(MyString);
}
```